# Access a folder from another user

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, apache2, samba

I'm working with PHP, and I'm trying to access a folder of another user, and I always get the error "Permission denied".

I have created a group, added both users and grant access. It doesn't help, and here is what I did (from root access):

```
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup tools
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup user2

sudo chgrp -R mygroup /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users

sudo chmod -R 2775 /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users

chmod ug+rwx -R /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users
```

Now, when I'm trying to access the folder from the user "tools" (where this folder is located), I can do it easily with no problem:

```
[tools@server ~]$ ls -l /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users
total 4
drwxrwsr-x 7 root mygroup 4096 Dec 18 17:36 id
```

But, if I try to access this folder from a different user (in the same group), I get this error:

```
[user2@server ~]$ ls -l /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users
ls: cannot access /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave access to `user2` to the specific sub-folder: `/home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users`

I assume that the reason you failed to access that folder by `user2` is that `user2` can't access some folders in the upper level of the folder hierarchy.

One possible way to solve it, might be added the `x` (change directory) permission to all directories above that folder to all users.

As user `tools` (or as `root` by using `sudo`) you can give the `x` permission on all directory (e.g.):

```
chmod +x /home/tools
chmod +x /home/tools/domains
chmod +x /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com
chmod +x /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html
chmod +x /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage
chmod +x /home/tools/domains/domain.tools.com/public_html/storage/users
```